# Visual studio memory profiling snapshot

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to use the memory profiler in VS 2010 Premium. Does it have the ability to take a snapshot of what is actually holding a reference to the objects rather than just where the objects are allocated?

thanks,

Stuart